# Optimize LEFT JOIN on table with 30 000+ rows

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, left-join

I have a website where visitors can leave comments. I want to add the ability to answer comments (i.e. nested comments).

At first this query was fast but after I populated the table with the existing comments (about 30000) a simple query like:

```
SELECT c.id, c2.id
  FROM (SELECT id
         FROM swb_comments
         WHERE pageId = 1411
         ORDER BY id DESC
         LIMIT 10) AS c
  LEFT JOIN swb_comments AS c2 ON c.id = c2.parentId
```

took over 2 seconds, with no childComments(!).

How do I optimize a query like this? On possible solution would be http://www.ferdychristant.com/blog//articles/DOMM-7QJPM7 (scroll to "The Flat Table Model done right") but this makes pagination rather difficult (how do I limit to 10 parent comments within 1 query?)

The table has 3 indexes, id, pageId and ParentId.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Table definition added. This is the full definition with some differences to the above SELECT query, (i.e. pageId instead of numberId to avoid confussion)

```
CREATE TABLE `swb_comments` (
    `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `userId` mediumint(9) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
    `numberId` mediumint(9) unsigned default NULL,
    `orgId` mediumint(9) unsigned default NULL,
    `author` varchar(100) default NULL,
    `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `message` text NOT NULL,
    `IP` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    `editedTimestamp` varchar(25) default NULL COMMENT 'last edited timestamp',
    `status` varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'publish',
    `parentId` mediumint(9) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
    `locale` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
    KEY `userId` (`userId`),
    KEY `numberId` (`numberId`),
    KEY `orgId` (`orgId`),
    KEY `parentId` (`parentId`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=34748 ;
```

Comment: Are you planning to do unlimited nesting? (ie. you can respond again to an answer?) Or just one level deep max?

Comment: What does the EXPLAIN have to say?

Comment: Is SELECT id FROM swb_comments WHERE pageId = 1411 LIMIT 10 slow as well? how many hits are you getting from the parent id join?

Comment: Without an ORDER BY in the sub-select, you are selecting comments practically at random. Is this the intent?

Comment: @Daniel I only want one level (Facebook-style).
@Sam SELECT id FROM swb_comments WHERE numberId =1411 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10 is only 0.0024 sec, so no. At this time I have only imported all rows from the old table so there is no child comments at all.
@Marcelo Thanks for the ORDER BY, is sliced of 0.2 sec which is great. I updated the question to include it.

Comment: @Brian I put the explain output here: http://carl-fredrik.net/explain.html. I really have to read up on EXPLAIN.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that MySQL cannot apply index if it need to deal with a result from a derived query (that's why you have NULL in the  possible_keys column). So I suggest to filter out ten comments that you need:

```
SELECT * FROM swb_comments WHERE pageId = 1411 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

And after that send separate request to get answers for each comment id:

```
SELECT * FROM swb_comments WHERE parentId IN ($commentId1, $commentId2, ..., $commentId10)
```

In this case database engine will be able to apply pageId and parentId indexes efficiently.

Comment: Normally, I'd downvote this, but having run into countless weird things with the MySQL optimizer that most other vendors don't have, I just have to nod my head in grave agreement.

Answer (score 0):

If Mr Fedorenko is correct and the subquery is causing the optimiser difficulties, could you not try...

```
SELECT c.id, c2.id
    FROM swb_comments c LEFT JOIN swb_comments c2 ON c.id = c2.parentID
    WHERE c.pageId = 1411
    ORDER BY c.id DESC
    LIMIT 10;
```

and see if it's any improvement?

Later - I have created a table using your definition, filled it in with 30,000 skeletal rows, and tried both the queries. They both complete in too short a time to notice. The explain plans are here...

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT c.id, c2.id
               FROM swb_comments c LEFT JOIN swb_comments c2 ON c.id = c2.parentID
               WHERE c.numberId = 1411     ORDER BY c.id DESC     LIMIT 10;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+------------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref        | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+------------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ref  | numberId      | numberId | 4       | const      |    1 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c2    | ref  | parentId      | parentId | 3       | books.c.id |   14 |                             |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+------------+------+-----------------------------+

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT c.id, c2.id
                   FROM swb_comments c LEFT JOIN swb_comments c2 ON c.id = c2.parentID
                   WHERE c.numberId = 1411     ORDER BY c.id DESC     LIMIT 10;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+------------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref        | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+------------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ref  | numberId      | numberId | 4       | const      |    1 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c2    | ref  | parentId      | parentId | 3       | books.c.id |   14 |                             |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+------------+------+-----------------------------+
```

and are exactly what I'd expect.

This is very mysterious.

I'll think about it a bit more to see if there's anything else we can try.

Comment: This was my original query, but it does not support pagination of parent comments. And this query is in fact much slower, about 32 sec.

Comment: Hmm. That surprises me. What does the EXPLAIN say about it?

Comment: I've updated http://carl-fredrik.net/explain.html with an EXPLAIN for the above query. I think the "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort" i the culprit here.

Comment: Yes, it's really not very fond of your indexes, is it? Perhaps we could have a look at your table definition.

Comment: The analyze table only says: Table is already up to date. Will give you the table definition tomorrow.

Comment: @Brian The question has been updated to include the table definition.

Comment: Later - have tried it, but am no nearer to solving the problem. A bit of a head-scratcher, this one.

Comment: I have thought about this a bit more and the only thing I can suggest is that you use mysqldump to create a script, and use the script to create a new table (of slightly different name) and see if the query does better on that.

Comment: Many many thanks! I will try that and report back. Again, thank you very much!